# Error running exercises from ThinkStats on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I am learning statistics and Python from this book called **ThinkStats**.  It has instructions on how to download the code and solve the exercises. I did everything that was told but am still not able to run the code on jupyter notebook. I am not sure what I am missing.  Can someone please help me? Here is a list of instructions in the book and the things I did till now.

"After you clone the repository or unzip the zip file, you should have a folder called **ThinkStats2/code** with a file called nsfg.py. If you run nsfg.py, it should read a data file, run some tests, and print a message like, “All tests passed.” If you get import errors, it probably means there are packages you need to install."

Till now I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it and got the file named nsfg.py.  I opened the file in jupyter notebook, but **I am getting an error called" cannot find module thinkstats2"**.  This module is specific to the book and from what I understand, the module is in the Thinkstats2 directory.  How do I make jupyter notebbok run the file in the ThinkStats 2 directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can run nsfg.py using the Python interpreter in your terminal.

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone git@github.com:AllenDowney/ThinkStats2.git
$ cd ThinkStats2/code/
$ python3 nsfg.py
(13593, 244)
All tests passed.
```

Alternatively, you can launch Jupyter Notebook in a specific directory:

```
$ jupyter-notebook --notebook-dir=~/ThinkStats2/
```

If you navigate to http://localhost:8888/tree in your browser, you should see the contents of the ThinkStats2 directory.  Then click "New" > "Python 3".

In the first cell block, enter `cd code`, and execute it.  In the second cell block, enter `%run nsfg.py`.  You should see the same message as with the Python interpreter.

[image]

---

Notice that you must be in the `code/` directory to run the file because it uses relative file path references.  This gets at a larger reason why I would not personally recommend learning Python with ThinkStats: it is statistically sound, but often it does not use the best Python practices and forms bad habit as a result.  In other words, `python ~/ThinkStats2/code/nsfg.py` will raise a `FileNotFoundError`, which is easily avoidable.